# Pivotal Web Services: Flyway Enterprise Edition or MySQL upgrade required

Tags: spring-boot, flyway, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I get the following message when deploying my Spring Boot Application to Pivotal Web Services with a MySQL cleardb spark database:

```
org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEditionUpgradeRequiredException: 
    Flyway Enterprise Edition or MySQL upgrade required: MySQL 5.6 is no longer supported by 
    Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Flyway Enterprise Edition.
```

I've tried deploying with Flyway v6.1.4. Are there any options other than ponying up $2950/yr for Flyway Enterprise? Can I run a more recent version of MySQL on Pivotal Web Services? Any good alternatives to Flyway?

Comment: This isn't an issue with Pivotal Web Services. PWS is simply asking ClearDb to create a database on your behalf. ClearDb is the one that creates & manages the DB. You would need to talk to ClearDb support to see when they will upgrade their databases.

Comment: Correct. It is not an issue with PWS. Flyway v6 throws an error when you attempt to pair it with MySQL v5.6. https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/0f8ac13/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/mysql/MySQLDatabase.java#L284

Comment: That doesn't sound like an error, it seems intentional & to let you know that's no longer a supported version. In a perfect world, you would upgrade the MySQL server, but since ClearDb is running it for you, it's up to them. For what it's worth, 5.6 is getting pretty old, it was GA in 2013, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Release_history

Comment: Agreed. I'll consider contacting ClearDB and asking if they could support a more recent version of MySQL.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Downgrading to Flyway v5.2.4 solved my issue.

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61558699/caused-by-org-flywaydb-core-api-flywayexception-migration-failed-and-spring ?

Comment: How did you downgrade Flyway? I haven't been able to specify any version other than the latest with homebrew.

Comment: Here is an example of how I did it with gradle. See build.gradle, gradle.properties, and the README: https://github.com/radavis/usaf-aircraft/tree/master/api

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded the FlyWay version that I had. Here is a sample:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
  <version>7.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with MySQL/MariaDB where the JDBC driver reports that the database is version 5.6 even though it is actually newer. On your database, what do you get if you execute `SELECT VERSION()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade the Spring-boot version to 2.0.1 or below then it will work absolutely fine, either downgrade the flyway version to v5.2.4 might solve this issue.
try downgrading the spring boot version to 2.0.1 which has stable and works great with 3rd party dependancies.