# Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Migration failed ! and Spring Cloud DataFlow

Tags: spring, flyway, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I'm working on `Spring batch and Spring Cloud Data Flow` example. In this example, I've developed `spring-cloud-data-flow-server` and MySQL DB instead of default H2 DB by taking reference from [Database Configs for MySQL DB](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_task_database_configuration)

**It looks like there is a issue with the Flyways and MySQL version as latest version of Flyways doesn't pickup the latest version of MySQL DB**.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: Migration failed !
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication.main(SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: Migration failed !
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:370) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$200(DbMigrate.java:54) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$3.call(DbMigrate.java:284) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:74) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigrations(DbMigrate.java:281) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:246) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$100(DbMigrate.java:54) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:164) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:161) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.mysql.MySQLNamedLockTemplate.execute(MySQLNamedLockTemplate.java:60) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.mysql.MySQLConnection.lock(MySQLConnection.java:147) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory.lock(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:155) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateAll(DbMigrate.java:161) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:139) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1395) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1356) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1711) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Migration failed !
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.java.JavaMigrationExecutor.execute(JavaMigrationExecutor.java:62) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:367) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [CREATE TABLE TASK_LOCK (
  LOCK_KEY CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  CLIENT_ID CHAR(36),
  CREATED_DATE DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
  constraint LOCK_PK primary key (LOCK_KEY, REGION)
)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=568) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:418) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.db.migration.SqlCommandsRunner.execute(SqlCommandsRunner.java:61) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:2.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.db.migration.AbstractMigration.migrate(AbstractMigration.java:46) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:2.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.java.JavaMigrationExecutor.execute(JavaMigrationExecutor.java:48) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=568) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:242) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:171) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:248) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:338) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:389) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:409) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
  constraint LOCK_PK primary key (LOCK_KEY, REGION)
)' at line 5
Query is: CREATE TABLE TASK_LOCK (
  LOCK_KEY CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  CLIENT_ID CHAR(36),
  CREATED_DATE DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
  constraint LOCK_PK primary key (LOCK_KEY, REGION)
)
java thread: main
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.LogQueryTool.exceptionWithQuery(LogQueryTool.java:126) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:234) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:332) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar:na]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-data-flow-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-cloud-data-flow-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server.version>2.4.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

spring.cloud.dataflow.features.streams-enabled=false
```

SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication.java

```
@EnableDataFlowServer
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran the `CREATE TABLE TASK_LOCK ...;` instruction locally on MySQL v8.0.19 (note the ending semicolon!), and I got a `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)` response. What version of MySQL is being used? If you can log into the database server with the `mysql` command, it will tell you.

Comment: Hey I am using MySQL 5.5, Do I need to upgrade it to latest version ? Could you please share complete query `CREATE TABLE TASK_LOCK ...;`

Comment: `CREATE TABLE TASK_LOCK (   LOCK_KEY CHAR(36) NOT NULL,   REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   CLIENT_ID CHAR(36),   CREATED_DATE DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,   constraint LOCK_PK primary key (LOCK_KEY, REGION) );`

Comment: Thanks for the details, when we start the cloud dataflow server, migration scripts execute and throws exception, I dont know when to execute the above script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL v5.5 doesn't accept an argument for the `DATETIME` datatype. Update your query to the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TASK_LOCK ( 
  LOCK_KEY CHAR(36) NOT NULL, 
  REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  CLIENT_ID CHAR(36), 
  CREATED_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL, -- note the omitted (6) argument --
  constraint LOCK_PK primary key (LOCK_KEY, REGION) 
);
```

Consider using the same MySQL version for local development as your remote deployment servers. This way, you won't be surprised by incompatibilities between the environments your application will run within.

Comment: Yes sure will follow, do you know which mysql version does SCDF server uses ? I am installing MySQL 8

Comment: Thanks. I've upgrade the MySQL to 8.0.11 which look stable version and works fine without making any changes in the pom.xml. The only thing I had to do is give full permissions to `root` user `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the latest version of flyway-core? Some issues were fixed in this area.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
  <version>6.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

More about it here: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2519

Comment: Should I try to install latest version of MySQL 8.0.x?